# Can't properly display characters using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some names of settlements from a website using a BeautifulSoup library. The website uses the **'windows-1250'** character set, but some of the characters are not displayed properly. See the last name of the settlement, which should be Župkov.

Could you help me with this problem?
This is the code:

```
# imports    
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString

# create beautifulsoup object
obce_url = 'http://www.e-obce.sk/zoznam_vsetkych_obci.html?strana=2500'
source_code = requests.get(obce_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
obce_soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

# define bs filter
def soup_filter_1(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('href') and len(tag.attrs) == 1 and isinstance(tag.next_element, NavigableString)

# print settlement names
for tag in obce_soup.find_all(soup_filter_1):
    print(tag.string)
```

I am using Python 3.5.1 and beautifulsoup 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with beautifulsoup, it just cannot determine what encoding you have ( try `print('encoding', obce_soup.original_encoding)`) and this is caused by you handing it Unicode instead of bytes.

If you try this:

```
obce_url = 'http://www.e-obce.sk/zoznam_vsetkych_obci.html?strana=2500'
source_code = requests.get(obce_url)
data_bytes = source_code.content  # don't use .text it will try to make Unicode
obce_soup = BeautifulSoup(data_bytes, 'html.parser')
print('encoding', obce_soup.original_encoding)
```

to create your beautifulsoup object, you'll see it now gets the encoding right and your output is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server sends HTTP headers which specify the character set as `UTF-8` but then the actual HTML uses `Win-1250`. So `requests` uses `UTF-8` to decode the HTML data.

But you can get original data `source_code.content` and use `decode('cp1250')` to get correct characters.

```
plain_text = source_code.content.decode('cp1250')
```

Or you can manually set `encoding` before you get `text`

```
source_code.encoding = 'cp1250'
plain_text = source_code.text
```

You can also use the original data `source_code.content` in `BS` so it should use information within the HTML about its encoding

```
 obce_soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'html.parser')
```

see

```
 print(obce_soup.declared_html_encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know site's encoding, you can just pass it explicitly to BeautifulSoup constructor with response's content, not text:

```
source_code = requests.get(obce_url)
content = source_code.content
obce_soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser', from_encoding='windows-1250')
```